# Impact of validation of package.xml having Sharing Rule

Tags: validation, package, production, sharing-rule

I am planning to deploy few sharing rules on Account, Contact object from UAT to PROD through package.xml. Before actual deployment, I would like to just **validate** the package against production environment? What will happen when I will perform the validation of package.xml against prod? Is it going to lock the records or start any kind of recalculation during validation?

Comment: I don't have a way to test this right now, but I suspect that doing so will not cause any additional locks than a deployment already causes, because the system wouldn't bother doing a recalculation only to discard the results.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to validation now. I will update once the validation is done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting the below error during validation when I am including multiple criteria based sharing rules in package.xml ... "sharing operation already in progress"